# Xdebug stop working and couldn't stops at breakpoints

Tags: php, phpstorm, xdebug

Yesterday debugger stopped working without any reason. I use PhpStorm IDE to debug. I put breakpoint at start of page and it doesn't stop on it.

I tried to debug console script with same PHP version and it works fine - debugging stoped on breakpoint. I changed php version on Apache server and tried degguning on another project - it works fine, debugging stops on breakpoint.

**PHP Version** 5.6.40-12+ubuntu18.04.1+deb.sury.org+1

**/etc/php/5.6/apache2/conf.d/20-xdebug.ini**

```
zend_extension=xdebug.so
xdebug.remote_connect_back=1
xdebug.remote_port=9000
xdebug.scream=0
xdebug.show_local_vars=1
xdebug.idekey=PHPSTORM
xdebug.remote_enable=1
xdebug.remote_log='/val/log/xdebug.log'
```

[image: **xdebug version**: 2.5.5]
[image: xdebug_config_1]

[image: xdebug_config_2]

**PhpStorm** 2019.2.3
Build #PS-192.6817.20, built on September 25, 2019
Runtime version: 11.0.4+10-b304.69 amd64
VM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM by JetBrains s.r.o
Linux 5.0.0-27-generic

While debugging start, PhpStorm log has warning. Maybe this helps:

```
2019-10-07 15:51:33,188 [25325256]   WARN - il.connection.ServerConnection - input stream is finished 
java.io.IOException: input stream is finished
    at com.jetbrains.php.debug.xdebug.dbgp.DbgpUtil.readDocument(DbgpUtil.java:115)
    at com.jetbrains.php.debug.xdebug.dbgp.DbgpUtil.readMessage(DbgpUtil.java:283)
    at com.jetbrains.php.debug.xdebug.connection.XdebugConnection$MyInputReader.read(XdebugConnection.java:135)
    at com.jetbrains.php.debug.xdebug.connection.XdebugConnection$MyInputReader.read(XdebugConnection.java:124)
    at com.jetbrains.php.debug.xdebug.connection.XdebugConnection.init(XdebugConnection.java:47)
    at com.jetbrains.php.debug.connection.PhpDebugServer.handle(PhpDebugServer.java:51)
    at com.jetbrains.php.debug.connection.PhpDebugServer.handle(PhpDebugServer.java:34)
    at com.jetbrains.php.util.connection.ServerConnection.lambda$null$0(ServerConnection.java:64)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl$1.run(ApplicationImpl.java:294)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:515)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
```

**How to fix problem, how to force xdebug stops on breakpoints?**

Comment: Would you mind providing additional details on phpinfo xdebug section? lower part, where `xdebug.remote_port`, `xdebug.remote_enable`, etc values are displayed.
And what about environment: do you run your php site in vagrant, docker, or locally?

Comment: @Yerke, screens added. Site stays locally, runs using apache2

Answer (score 4):

From the error message I can see that the debugging session does work. PhpStorm seems to abort the connection.

It's likely that Xdebug is sending XML that PhpStorm does not understand (i.e., it's invalid). I suspect it's either due to a null character in a property name or array key name. (Feel free to post the full log to a pastebin, I'm happy to look and amend the answer).

You are already creating a remote log file, so have a look at the last few lines that are in there, *just* after your debugging session aborts.

You can fix this issue by upgrading Xdebug to a supported version (2.7.2 at the moment).

Comment: here is logs: https://pastebin.com/rF3ZgbeV. It just has repeats of on log message. I already tried to start debug on older PhpStorm version 2019.2 - same result. And I can't upgrade Xdebug because I use php5.6, but last supported version is 2.5.5 (I tried to change xdebug to different at _20-xdebug.ini_ file - it stops working.

Comment: I wanted to see Xdebug's remote log file, not PhpStorm's. But if my hunch is right, you do need to update Xdebug for it to start working, and that also means upgrading PHP. PHP 5.6 has been discontinued for nearly 3 years now.

Comment: Xdebug doesn't logging anything to mention log  file. And upgrade php version is not a solution, our project work only on it.

Comment: Not sure what I can say then. This is fixed in a newer Xdebug version.

Comment: So, as I understand that the only one way to fix issue is to upgrade project to newer PHP, isn't it @Derick?